# SSH: Tunnel multiple ports to remote server

Tags: networking, ssh, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel

See attached diagram.

- Host A - Windows server
- Host B - Linux server
- Host C - VMWare ESXi server

From host A I can SSH to host B over the VPN tunnel. I can ping host C from host B, but not from host A. I am assuming this is because host C has lost its default gateway.

Host C is a VMWware ESXi server, so I would need to tunnel several ports (80,443,902) in order to reach host C from host A.

What is the correct ssh syntax to create the tunnel in order to reach host C from host A, and can I do it using a single command, or do I need to run three commands (one for each port, 80,443,902)?

[image: Network Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I accomplished this.

- Host A - 192.168.10.6
- Host B - 10.18.3.20
- Host C - 10.18.3.10

Then these commands:

- ssh -f -L 10.18.3.20:80:10.18.3.10:80 10.18.3.20 -N
- ssh -f -L 10.18.3.20:443:10.18.3.10:443 10.18.3.20 -N
- ssh -f -L 10.18.3.20:902:10.18.3.10:902 10.18.3.20 -N

Then pointed the vSphere client on Host A to 10.18.3.20, which connected me to 10.18.3.10 and I was able to change the default gateway.